# NetLogo: Apply set [variable] from sub-procedure to global process?

Tags: netlogo

I want to simulate **reproduction process of turtles in time when single patch can by used only once**. If the patch is red and `ticks mod 50 = 0` then `turtles-here` (on this patch) `hatch` new 10 turtles.  Every patch can be used only once during the whole simulation run.

Please, how can I include this condition into my code? I tried simple to change patch color to `green` with hope that the next hatching process will run only with `red` ones. However next time step NetLogo doesn't keep this patch green but changes it back to red. Thus my reproduction run from the same patch.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

The part of my code:

```
to go
  if ticks mod 50 = 0 [ask patches with [pcolor= red] [reproduce] ]
end

to reproduce 
  ask one-of turtles-here 
      [hatch 10 ; 
        die]
       ; set pcolor green       - change infestlev from 2 to 5 only for specific tick, not for the rest of the simulation
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have should work fine. In your description, you state that the colour turns back to red - so that's why this code isn't working, somewhere else you have a colouring procedure. Alternatively, if you don't want to rely on colour (or if you want colours to mean something else), then you can add a variable to each patch to keep track of whether it has already reproduced.

```
patches-own [reproduced?]

to setup
  ...
  ask patches [set reproduced? FALSE]
  ...
end

to go
  if ticks mod 50 = 0 [ask patches with [not reproduced?] [reproduce] ]
end

to reproduce
  ask one-of turtles-here 
  [ hatch 10
    die ]
  set reproduced? TRUE
end
```

Just as a general comment, it is a little odd to ask the patch to reproduce when what you are really trying to do is have the turtle on a patch reproduce. Logically you are saying that once one turtle on a patch has reproduced, then no other turtle on that patch can ever reproduce. If the reproduction is truly governed by the patch, it would be more usual to use `sprout` instead of `hatch`. That gets you code that looks like this:

```
to reproduce
  sprout 10 [ any commands you want the new turtles to do ]
  set reproduced? TRUE
end
```

Comment: Thank you @JenB it seems to work! I've just added "?" into 'ask patches [set reproduced? FALSE]' in SETUP procedure. And thank you for SPROUT, yes I think this will be the better approach for my needs ! :) and I have finally understood how to use ? in my variables :)

Comment: sorry about that, now fixed. I didn't have the full code so couldn't test it and had the typo in the variable name. The ? at the end is a NetLogo convention for variables that take only the values TRUE or FALSE (referred to as boolean variables). When used this way, as a marker to ensure something only happens once, they are also sometimes called flags.

Answer (score 1):

My final working code with steps (available here: http://ulozto.cz/xRqtDDfV/timing-of-turtle-sprout-nlogo):

1. setup turtles
2. if turtle touch red patch, turn this patch blue
3. at the same time - tick 10 -> sprout from every blue patch 10 nwe turtles
4. every patch can be used only once during simulation run (turn red, assured by reproduced? variable)

[image]

`enter code here`

```
patches-own [reproduced?]    

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  setup-patches
  change-color
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set reproduced? FALSE]
  ask patches [set pcolor green]           
  ask n-of 80 patches [set pcolor red]        ; identify turles which could be a source for new turtles
end  

to setup-turtles
  crt 1
  ask turtles [set color yellow]
end


to go
  if ticks mod 10 = 0 [
                       ask patches with [(pcolor = blue) and not (reproduced?)] 
                       [reproduce]               ; set reproduction to every 10 ticks for all blue patches
                      ]
  move-turtles
  change-color
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [fd 1]
end

to change-color                ; if turtle touch red patch, red turns blue
  ask turtles [if pcolor = red  
    [set pcolor blue]
  ]
end

to reproduce                  ; sprout 10 new turtles from blue patches at defined time step (multiply of 10 ticks)
  sprout 10   
  set reproduced? TRUE
end
```